# Azure Data Factory Expression to Check if Property is Defined

Tags: json, null, azure-data-factory

I am working with JSON structured data in ADF and trying to implement an IF condition where, if a property is defined in JSON, I will execute one path, another if not defined.

For example, consider the JSON data:

```
{
 "name" : "sh"
 "RareProperty" : "rarevalue"
}
```

`RareProperty` may or may not exist depending on scenario.

If I try to reference `RareProperty` in the If Condition block, I get an error saying *property RareProperty not defined*, which is understandable as the property isn't actually defined in the scenario.

I am looking for a way to check if a property is defined without getting any error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the ? something like

> @{body('yourresponse')?['RareProperty']}

Comment: This works in Logic Apps, not sure if the syntax is same in ADF.